# How to use javascript in joomla to a specific page

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.3.3. I want to use javascript on specific page. How can i use it?

Comment: Please check my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26388756/3834042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are variety of plugins you can use this purpose.  If you are JavaScript needs to be loaded in the HEAD tags, most of these components allow it.  Read the component descriptions to get a better idea.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules